# update a cell of a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-update

I have these lines in `views/admins/index.html.erb`

I tried to update my `User` table in the cell of the role_ids after pressing on `update`:

if `worker.role_ids` is [1], it will change to [2].
if `worker.role_ids` is [2], it will change to [1].

```
<td><%= worker.email %></td>
<td><%= worker.role_ids %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'edit', edit_admin_path(worker) %></td>
```

I can define `edit` and `_form`, but there is no elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via Ajax (I think that it is what you are looking for). You can call a remote action, passing the id of the object, and calling a method to update to the corresponding value. For example:

View

```
<%= link_to 'Change Role', change_admin_role_path(worker.id), :remote => true %>
```

Controller

```
def change_admin_role
   @worker = User.find(params[:id])
   @worker.change_role
end
```

Remember to **add the route**, also **create the method change_role in the User model** that will evaluate the actual value and make the change, and **create a change_admin_role.js.coffee** (or change_admin_role.js.erb) to make the changes over the view via Ajax.